# Move AWS snapshot to S3 bucket

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, snapshot

I want to move my EBS snapshot into my S3 bucket, but after researching a lot i didn't find the way.
Is there any possible way to do it.

Comment: _Why_ do you wish to do this?

Answer (score 2):

Amazon EBS Snapshots use Amazon S3 for storage, but they cannot be moved into your own Amazon S3 bucket.